# Looking for an elegant way to parse an Integer

Tags: go

Right now I am doing the following in order to parse an integer from a string and then convert it to `int` type:

```
tmpValue, _ := strconv.ParseInt(str, 10, 64) //returns int64
finalValue = int(tmpValue)
```

It is quite verbose, and definitely not pretty, since I haven't found a way to do the conversion in the `ParseInt` call. Is there a nicer way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the function [`strconv.Atoi`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi) does what you want, except that it works regardless of the bit size of `int` (your code seems to assume it's 64 bits wide).

Answer (score 3):

If you have to write that once in your program than I see no problem. If you need at several places you can write a simple specialization wrapper, for example:

```
func parseInt(s string) (int, error) {
        i, err := strconv.ParseInt(str, 10, 32)  // or 64 on 64bit tip
        return int(i), err
}
```

The standard library doesn't aim to supply (bloated) APIs for every possible numeric type and/or their combinations.

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the `base` argument, which wasn't being used. Otherwise, +1.

Comment: Actually, the point about "bloated APIs" is a bit off, since this particular case *is* covered by `strconv.Atoi`.

Comment: true. You could also call that a lack of generics in Go, but I understand from Pike's blog and other places that I'm not supposed to complain about that ;)

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to check for errors. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    s := "123"
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Output:

```
123
```